# How to Pass argument to Oozie

Tags: scala, apache-spark, oozie

My use case is the following, I am building an Oozie Pipeline and i need to pass it an argument.

Indeed my spark job must receive a string date as an argument and it would be great to pass the argument to the Oozie Workflow in order to use it in the Spark Submit. Anyone got any idea ? I didn't find the answer on Google

Thanks

Comment: You can replace the date at runtime in your properties file and the pass the variable defined in properties file as an argument to spark.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not exactly what I'm looking for because i would like to pass as an argument any date and not only the current date with the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create workflow.xml that references some variable `inputDate`
2. Create
   file job.properties that defines default value for `inputDate`
3. Run
   your job using CLI, overriding default value when is needed:
   `oozie job -run -config job.properties -DinputDate=2017-08-19`